# Glittering blob in 3D matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, 3d

How can I make a scatter plot in 3D Python while having one of the points glittering (going on & off) continuously ? Can we do it with matolotlib.animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Using FuncAnimation you can do this, keep track of the one point you want to blink and change the color for every frame, look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/random_walk.html?highlight=animation and change the required things to scatterplots in stead of lines.